# What minimal permission a Global Admin user should have to retrieve data via CSOM API from site collection?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, csom

I am trying to get some content from site collections in O365 via CSOM API.
I am using the **Global Administrator** account and getting the following error:     *Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.*

If I give the Global Administrator user that I use the Site Collection Administrator permission, then I am not getting the exception.

Is it possible to give the Global Admin another **less powerful then Site Collection Administrator**  to achieve the same result?
If no, is there any other API that doesn't require adding the Site Collection Administrator permissions to the Global Administrator?

Comment: Edited the post since owner permission =/= site collection permission, and i refereed owner  like it is a site collection administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Global administrator and site collection administrator have 2 different roles it is essential to add Site Collection permission to the Global administrator account.
You can find more details at the following link : https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164763/sharepoint-online-administrator-is-site-collection-administrator

Answer (score 0):

The global administrator should have full access through the whole tenant and shouldn't require you to modify its permissions to access the api. Do you definately mean the global admin account that was used to setup the tenant? Or have you created another account and assigned it global admin access?

Comment: 100% sure , I also succeed adding the site collection admin permission to the global Administrator user account using the    public virtual User SetSiteAdmin(string url, string loginName, bool isSiteAdmin);